# How to keep column name after sum aggregation in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum, alias

I am querying SQL Server where I have multiple columns with sum aggregation. I'm wondering if there is a way to keep column name after doing sum over each of them.

I want to avoid using aliases immediately after the selected column as their numbers and names change over time.

Example of my result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAWWu.png]

My query:

```sql
DECLARE @SQLQUERY AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

DECLARE @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SumColumns as NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumns = COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',','') + QUOTENAME(description)
FROM [example-base].dbo.table

SELECT @SumColumns = 'sum('+Replace(@PivotColumns,',','),sum(')+')'

SET @SQLQUERY = N'SELECT TOP(100) Weeks, Years, Code,'+@SumColumns+ '
FROM [example-base].dbo.table
group by Weeks,Years,Code'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQUERY
```

Is there a way to keep column name on which is done sum?

Comment: The only option is to add an explicit alias as far as I know.

Comment: Be aware that what you're doing to concatenate a string is [not reliable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks): "Don't use a variable in a SELECT statement to concatenate values (that is, to compute aggregate values). Unexpected query results may occur. Because, all expressions in the SELECT list (including assignments) aren't necessarily run exactly once for each output row"

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
I'm afraid you are right. I was hoping there was a way to do it, though I didn't find a solution on the web.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever
Thanks for watching, I was reckless with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be aware of the potential performance issues by building a query with text. Moreover, your result may be not predictable while the number of columns can evolve between two executions.

To add an alias to your columns, you may use this statement :

```
DECLARE @SumColumns AS nvarchar(MAX);

SELECT @SumColumns = CONCAT(COALESCE(@PivotColumns + ',', ''), 'SUM(', QUOTENAME(description), ') AS ', QUOTENAME(description))
FROM [example-base].dbo.table
```

Comment: Thanks, works pretty well. I'm aware of performance risk. My overall list of description is constant, but can vary over different Codes, therefore I think I'm able to verify execution of each of them

Answer (score 0):

...a union..?

```
SET @SQLQUERY = N'
SELECT TOP(0) Weeks, Years, Code,'+@PivotColumns+ '
FROM [example-base].dbo.table
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP(100) Weeks, Years, Code,'+@SumColumns+ '
FROM [example-base].dbo.table
group by Weeks,Years,Code'
```